# Include empty columns when reading xlsx spreadsheet into R?

Tags: r, xlsx

I am using XLSX package to read an .xlsx file, the columns that do not contain any entries are not being captured (skipped).

code:

```
wb     <- loadWorkbook(".xlsx")
sheet1 <- getSheets(wb)[[2]]

rows <- getRows(newsheet)[2:3]
  headerdata <- getCells(rows[1]) %>% lapply(., getCellValue) %>% as.data.frame()
  rowdata <- getCells(rows[2])%>% lapply(., getCellValue) %>% as.data.frame()
   names(rowdata) <- headerdata [RECEIVES ERROR MESSAGE 'names' attribute [17] must be the same length as the vector [14]]
```

Any inputs would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't have the "xlsx" package, so I can't be of a lot of help. However, if you use "openxlsx", it should read columns that are empty (assuming it has a column name) ```library(openxlsx)

write.xlsx(cbind(mtcars, "Empty" = NA), "test.xlsx")
read.xlsx("test.xlsx")```

Comment: Thanks. As mentioned, I'm using .xlsx package that has functions to parse/read color codes(values) of the excel files.